# getchar() in assembly language

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, getchar

This is a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output of gcc command "gcc prog.c -S":

```
    .file   "prog.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    call getchar
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.8.2-1) 4.8.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

In "main" there is a call to "getchar" function. Is possible to see the code (in assembly, of course) of this function?

In particular I would understand the mechanism of keyboard interrupt behind the "getchar()".

Comment: That's part of your C library, and would depend greatly on the OS. On Linux, that's glibc, to which you can get source code to look at, and it just issues a non-blocking read to /dev/tty. On Windows or Mac, good luck finding source code. https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=libio;h=76735d501dfdd7029d6faa3e4037362f8711d1e8;hb=HEAD

Comment: you can use objdump to disassemble glibc

Comment: you just go and download the source of glibc. in any debian distributed version: `apt-get source glibc`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, not in any debian distributed version, they used eglibc recently

Comment: @myaut in my debian it does the work. it seems they put glibc as an alias of eglibc.

Comment: @myaut FYI, it's very funny, now debian is switching back. glibc now is in jessie and no eglibc any more. https://www.debian.org/News/weekly/2014/11/#Deb_GLIBC

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, that's what I meant by saying "recently" ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an ASM output you can simply ask `gdb` to load your C program and disassemble `getchar` for you.
This would give something like this (on my system) :

```
$ gdb /bin/cat
(gdb) run
Starting program: /bin/cat 
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7b0c5c0 in __read_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
(gdb) disas getchar 
Dump of assembler code for function getchar:
   0x00007ffff7aa4b30 <+0>:     push   %rbx
   0x00007ffff7aa4b31 <+1>:     mov    0x332be0(%rip),%rbx        # 0x7ffff7dd7718 <stdin>
   0x00007ffff7aa4b38 <+8>:     mov    (%rbx),%eax
   0x00007ffff7aa4b3a <+10>:    mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0x00007ffff7aa4b3d <+13>:    and    $0x8000,%eax
   0x00007ffff7aa4b42 <+18>:    jne    0x7ffff7aa4b9e <getchar+110>
   0x00007ffff7aa4b44 <+20>:    mov    0x88(%rbx),%rdx
   0x00007ffff7aa4b4b <+27>:    mov    %fs:0x10,%r8
   0x00007ffff7aa4b54 <+36>:    cmp    0x8(%rdx),%r8
   0x00007ffff7aa4b58 <+40>:    je     0x7ffff7aa4bf0 <getchar+192>
   0x00007ffff7aa4b5e <+46>:    mov    $0x1,%esi
   0x00007ffff7aa4b63 <+51>:    cmpl   $0x0,0x336c6a(%rip)        # 0x7ffff7ddb7d4 <__libc_multiple_threads>
   0x00007ffff7aa4b6a <+58>:    je     0x7ffff7aa4b78 <getchar+72>
   0x00007ffff7aa4b6c <+60>:    lock cmpxchg %esi,(%rdx)
   0x00007ffff7aa4b70 <+64>:    jne    0x7ffff7aa4c41 <_L_lock_30>
   0x00007ffff7aa4b76 <+70>:    jmp    0x7ffff7aa4b81 <getchar+81>
   0x00007ffff7aa4b78 <+72>:    cmpxchg %esi,(%rdx)
   0x00007ffff7aa4b7b <+75>:    jne    0x7ffff7aa4c41 <_L_lock_30>
   0x00007ffff7aa4b81 <+81>:    mov    0x88(%rbx),%rax
   0x00007ffff7aa4b88 <+88>:    mov    0x88(%rbx),%rdx
   0x00007ffff7aa4b8f <+95>:    mov    0x332b82(%rip),%rdi        # 0x7ffff7dd7718 <stdin>
   0x00007ffff7aa4b96 <+102>:   mov    %r8,0x8(%rax)
   0x00007ffff7aa4b9a <+106>:   addl   $0x1,0x4(%rdx)
   0x00007ffff7aa4b9e <+110>:   mov    0x8(%rdi),%rax
   0x00007ffff7aa4ba2 <+114>:   cmp    0x10(%rdi),%rax
   0x00007ffff7aa4ba6 <+118>:   jae    0x7ffff7aa4bf5 <getchar+197>
   0x00007ffff7aa4ba8 <+120>:   lea    0x1(%rax),%rdx
   0x00007ffff7aa4bac <+124>:   mov    %rdx,0x8(%rdi)
   0x00007ffff7aa4bb0 <+128>:   movzbl (%rax),%edx
   0x00007ffff7aa4bb3 <+131>:   testl  $0x8000,(%rbx)
   0x00007ffff7aa4bb9 <+137>:   jne    0x7ffff7aa4be4 <getchar+180>
   0x00007ffff7aa4bbb <+139>:   mov    0x88(%rbx),%rsi
   0x00007ffff7aa4bc2 <+146>:   subl   $0x1,0x4(%rsi)
   0x00007ffff7aa4bc6 <+150>:   jne    0x7ffff7aa4be4 <getchar+180>
   0x00007ffff7aa4bc8 <+152>:   movq   $0x0,0x8(%rsi)
   0x00007ffff7aa4bd0 <+160>:   cmpl   $0x0,0x336bfd(%rip)        # 0x7ffff7ddb7d4 <__libc_multiple_threads>
   0x00007ffff7aa4bd7 <+167>:   je     0x7ffff7aa4be0 <getchar+176>
   0x00007ffff7aa4bd9 <+169>:   lock decl (%rsi)
   0x00007ffff7aa4bdc <+172>:   jne    0x7ffff7aa4c5c <_L_unlock_79>
   0x00007ffff7aa4bde <+174>:   jmp    0x7ffff7aa4be4 <getchar+180>
   0x00007ffff7aa4be0 <+176>:   decl   (%rsi)
   0x00007ffff7aa4be2 <+178>:   jne    0x7ffff7aa4c5c <_L_unlock_79>
   0x00007ffff7aa4be4 <+180>:   mov    %edx,%eax
   0x00007ffff7aa4be6 <+182>:   pop    %rbx
   0x00007ffff7aa4be7 <+183>:   retq   
   0x00007ffff7aa4be8 <+184>:   nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x00007ffff7aa4bf0 <+192>:   mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0x00007ffff7aa4bf3 <+195>:   jmp    0x7ffff7aa4b9a <getchar+106>
   0x00007ffff7aa4bf5 <+197>:   callq  0x7ffff7aa9060 <__GI___uflow>
   0x00007ffff7aa4bfa <+202>:   mov    %eax,%edx
   0x00007ffff7aa4bfc <+204>:   jmp    0x7ffff7aa4bb3 <getchar+131>
   0x00007ffff7aa4bfe <+206>:   testl  $0x8000,(%rbx)
   0x00007ffff7aa4c04 <+212>:   mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x00007ffff7aa4c07 <+215>:   jne    0x7ffff7aa4c39 <getchar+265>
   0x00007ffff7aa4c09 <+217>:   mov    0x88(%rbx),%rdx
   0x00007ffff7aa4c10 <+224>:   mov    0x4(%rdx),%eax
   0x00007ffff7aa4c13 <+227>:   lea    -0x1(%rax),%ecx
   0x00007ffff7aa4c16 <+230>:   test   %ecx,%ecx
   0x00007ffff7aa4c18 <+232>:   mov    %ecx,0x4(%rdx)
   0x00007ffff7aa4c1b <+235>:   jne    0x7ffff7aa4c39 <getchar+265>
   0x00007ffff7aa4c1d <+237>:   movq   $0x0,0x8(%rdx)
   0x00007ffff7aa4c25 <+245>:   cmpl   $0x0,0x336ba8(%rip)        # 0x7ffff7ddb7d4 <__libc_multiple_threads>
   0x00007ffff7aa4c2c <+252>:   je     0x7ffff7aa4c35 <getchar+261>
   0x00007ffff7aa4c2e <+254>:   lock decl (%rdx)
   0x00007ffff7aa4c31 <+257>:   jne    0x7ffff7aa4c77 <_L_unlock_150>
   0x00007ffff7aa4c33 <+259>:   jmp    0x7ffff7aa4c39 <getchar+265>
   0x00007ffff7aa4c35 <+261>:   decl   (%rdx)
   0x00007ffff7aa4c37 <+263>:   jne    0x7ffff7aa4c77 <_L_unlock_150>
   0x00007ffff7aa4c39 <+265>:   mov    %rsi,%rdi
   0x00007ffff7aa4c3c <+268>:   callq  0x7ffff7a54d50 <_Unwind_Resume>
End of assembler dump.
```

You could also look directly at [the source of your libc](http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.21/getchar_8c_source.html) to see how getchar is implemented, however this will give you (perhaps sometimes cryptic) C code.

Comment: This sort of proves my initial thought on the question: disassembling the function `getchar` will show the underlying layer, which does *not* necessarily "handles keyboard interrupts". It's just the first step down a rabbit hole. I can't wait to see how deep it actually is.

Comment: @Jongware If you go deep enough you should end up seeing the syscall interface getting called, and then it's straight into kernel code, another rabbit hole but a *much* deeper one :)

Answer (score 3):

`getchar()` implementation lives in `libc.so` - standard C library implementation on your system (applies to Unix-like systems), so you need to apply disassembler to that library file.

Easiest way to do that is to use `gdb` debugger (again, Unix-specific):

1. Compile and *link* your program with `libc.so`:

   ```
   $ gcc -o prog prog.c
   ```
2. Run GDB:

   ```
   $ gdb prog
   ```
3. Run your program so PLT tables of `libc.so` will be populated and immediately stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>:

   ```
   ...
   (gdb) r
   ^C
   ```
4. Apply `disas` subcommand of `gdb` on `getchar()`:

   ```
   (gdb) disas getchar
   ```
5. Have fun reading low-level assembly

---

> In particular I would understand the mechanism of keyboard interrupt behind the "getchar()".

No, you do not. There are several layers between `getchar()` and hardware keyboard interrupts mostly implemented by Linux Kernel:

- Standard C library
- syscalls - a door from userspace to a OS kernel
- tty subsystem or pipes
- input subsystem
- (optional) USB drivers including `usbhid` or `usbkbd`
- basic kernel, including IRQ infrastructure

Reading all that sources in disassembly will take years. You need to look at architecture from the top.

Comment: And about "int 21h"? This intruction is valid in Windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

here is the source code for getchar(), in C.

you can compile it, while asking for the intermediate .asm file
to acquire what you want.

```
/* Copyright (C) 1993-2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
2  This file is part of the GNU C Library.
3 
4  The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
5  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
6  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
7  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
8 
9  The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
10  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
11  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
12  Lesser General Public License for more details.
13 
14  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
15  License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
16  <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
17 
18  As a special exception, if you link the code in this file with
19  files compiled with a GNU compiler to produce an executable,
20  that does not cause the resulting executable to be covered by
21  the GNU Lesser General Public License. This exception does not
22  however invalidate any other reasons why the executable file
23  might be covered by the GNU Lesser General Public License.
24  This exception applies to code released by its copyright holders
25  in files containing the exception. */
26 
27 #include "libioP.h"
28 #include "stdio.h"
29 
30 #undef getchar
31 
32 int
33 getchar (void)
34 {
35  int result;
36  _IO_acquire_lock (_IO_stdin);
37  result = _IO_getc_unlocked (_IO_stdin);
38  _IO_release_lock (_IO_stdin);
39  return result;
40 }
41 
42 #if defined weak_alias && !defined _IO_MTSAFE_IO
43 #undef getchar_unlocked
44 weak_alias (getchar, getchar_unlocked)
45 #endif
```

Comment: How can I produce a .asm file? (I know only "gcc prog.c -S" that return a .s file)